# flutter debug on device will killed when Connectivity change from none to wifi/mobile

Tags: flutter, connectivity

When I test pub `connectivity`'s feature, with iPhone device. Every time I connect to wifi from no internet. 
Log shows bellow:

```
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

I have create this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36609)